# High contrast page, jQuery toggle class, if class is there and changing url put this class on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, high-contrast

So I'm trying to make a button on page that changes it to high contrast page on click, it is working already, but if I go to different link on this page this high contrast class is not there and I need to click my button again to have page in high contrast. This is not very useful. I'm trying to write some function, maybe if condition that if there is a class 'high contrast' on element and my url changes, this class will be still there on a new url. Is it even possible? Can someone help me?

And for changing class to 'high contrast' I'm using jQuery .togglelass(). Maybe I should use something different than this?

Wrote something like this for changing my page to high contrast, just changing classes where I need to put high contrast.

```
$('.change-contrast').click( function() {
    $('.accessibility-icons span').toggleClass('high-contrast');
    $('a').toggleClass('high-contrast');
    $('.post-short').toggleClass('post-short-contrast');        
    $('.contact-page-container').toggleClass('contact-page-container-contrast');        
    $('.hours-container').toggleClass('hours-container-contrast');              
    $('.site').toggleClass('site-high-contrast');
    $('.site-footer').toggleClass('site-info-contrast');        
    $('.footer-info').toggleClass('footer-info-contrast');
    $('.bip').toggleClass('bip-contrast');
    $('.form-wrapper').toggleClass('form-wrapper-contrast');
    $('.menu-item').toggleClass('menu-item-contrast');
    $('.header-carousel_title').toggleClass('header-carousel_title-contrast');
    $('.logo-carousel').toggleClass('logo-carousel-contrast');
    $('.home-title').toggleClass('home-title-contrast');
    $('.hours-title').toggleClass('hours-title-contrast');      
    $('.page-main-title').toggleClass('page-main-title-contrast');      
    $('.gallery-title').toggleClass('gallery-title-contrast');      
    $('article').toggleClass('article-contrast');
    $('.owl-item').toggleClass('owl-item-contrast');
    $('.gallery-container').toggleClass('gallery-container-contrast');
    $('.gallery-button').toggleClass('gallery-button-contrast');
    $('.page-link-button').toggleClass('page-link-button-contrast');
    $('.post-short_title').toggleClass('post-short_title-contrast');    
    $('.excerpt').toggleClass('excerpt-contrast');                      
})
```

This page is really colorful, so I had to change a lot in it.

Comment: So use a cookie and read the cookie value when the page loads. I am amazed you did not just use one class on the body. Seems crazy to have to add tons of classes.

Comment: @epascarello maybe each class has its own unique styling in css

Comment: Can you provide a minimal fiddle for us to play with?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt so... `.high-contrast .post-short_title {} .high-contrast .excerpt {}` One class .... still all different

Comment: @epascarello I used different classes because those are different elements and they have unique styles, but maybe you are right, but still this is not my problem

Comment: Yes, but on class on the body would do the same thing with the selectors I showed. Think about it, if you add another element in the future, you need to update the CSS and you need to update the JavaScript. Just adding one class, and adjusting your CSS rules to look for that class means only change the the CSS is needed, not both. And it is more efficient than adding 30 classes.

Comment: I need that class to be there when I change an url, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Set a cookie, read the cookie, if there, call your function.